# Can I use AsyncTask inside ListFragment? or should I use AsyncTaskLoader?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-tabhost, android-listfragment, asynctaskloader

I tried the code below and also tried the `AsyncTaskLoader` approach. The app crashes when I instantiate the `AsyncTask`. Pleas advise me on the best approach to load JSON in a list fragment inside tab host.

The code below is the tab fragment (I use action bar tabs in main activity):

```
public class TabTop extends ListFragment {
Context context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
String API_URL = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/similar.json?apikey=crhhxb4accwwa6cy6fxrm8vj&limit=1";
ArrayList<Deal> deals;
DealsListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int a = 0;
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GetTopDeals getTopDeals = new GetTopDeals(context);
    getTopDeals.execute(API_URL);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}


class GetTopDeals extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Deal>>{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public GetTopDeals(Context activity) {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Deal> result) {
        adapter = new DealsListAdapter(context, result);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading Top deals...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Deal> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = sendRequest(urls[0]); // make request for json
        return processResponse(response); // parse the Json and return ArrayList to postExecute

    }

    private String sendRequest(String apiUrl) {
        BufferedReader input = null; // get the json
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = null; // the http connection object
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // hold all the data from the jason in string separated with "\n"

        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (httpCon.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // check for connectivity with server
                return null;
            }
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream())); // pull all the json from the site
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (httpCon != null) {
                httpCon.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Deal> processResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response); // Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string.
        JSONArray results = responseObject.getJSONArray("movies"); // Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray.
        deals = new ArrayList<Deal>();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) { // in this loop i copy the json array to movies arraylist in order to display  listView
            JSONObject jMovie = results.getJSONObject(i);
            int api_id = jMovie.getInt("id");
            String name = jMovie.getString("title");
            String content = jMovie.getString("synopsis");
            JSONObject posters = jMovie.getJSONObject("posters");
            String image_url = posters.getString("profile"); 
        }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return deals;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), DealInformation.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your asynctask in his own file.

And when your asynctask is finish, implement OnPostExecute which is automatically call. Notify your adapter by a notifyDataSetChanged like that :

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<NewItem> list) {
    Adapter.getListe().clear();     
    Adapter.getListe().addAll(list);
    Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you guys,

i want to post my answer. after some research i decided to go with AsyncTaskLoader.
this is my code

```
public class TabOurPicks extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<String[]>  {

// when activity loads- onActivityCreated() calls the initLoader() who activate onCreateLoader()
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{}));
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null,this).forceLoad();
}

// onCreateLoader instantiate the asynctaskloaser who work in bg
@Override
public RSSLoader onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    return new RSSLoader(getActivity());  // 
}

// after bg process invoke onLoadFinished() who work in ui thread
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String[]> loader, String[] data) {
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data
) );

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String[]> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

and this is the inner class for the loader:

```
static public class RSSLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String[]>
{
    public RSSLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] loadInBackground() {
        String url = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/770672122/similar.json?apikey=crhhxb4accwwa6cy6fxrm8vj&limit=1";
        String response = sendRequest(url);
        return processResponse(response);
    }


    private String sendRequest(String url) {
        BufferedReader input = null; // get the json
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = null; // the http connection object
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // hold all the data from the jason in string separated with "\n"

        try {
            URL apiUrl = new URL(url);
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) apiUrl.openConnection();

            if (httpCon.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // check for connectivity with server
                return null;
            }
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream())); // pull all the json from the site
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (httpCon != null) {
                httpCon.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    private String[] processResponse(String response) {
        String[] deals = null;
        try {
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response); // Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string.
            JSONArray results = responseObject.getJSONArray("movies"); // Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray.
            deals = new String[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // in this loop i copy the json array to movies arraylist in order to display  listView
                JSONObject jMovie = results.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jMovie.getString("title");
                deals[i] = name;
            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return deals;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if your asynctask has its own file.  You just don't want your activity to extends asynctask as this would make your activity asynchronous - but this is impossible to do anyways due to java's double inheritance rule.

Based on the architecture of your app and your programming style the asyntask can be an inner class in the activity.  on the PostExecute method make sure you have given data to your adapter and that the adapter is set to the list, then just run notifyDataSetChanged().

Assuming your asynctask is loading data from cache or the network you are on the right track with your approach to this.